# Change data type per dataframe column based on a dataframe of predefined data types in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have values dataframe consisting of character columns and a properties dataframe consisting of the column names of the values dataframe and a predefined data type. I need to check if the values data types are consistent with the predefined data type. Therefore I want to change the data types in the values dataframe based on the predefined data types in the properties dataframe in an automated way using map(), apply() or a for loop, preferably a tidy(verse) solution.

Below is an example but the actual dataset has a lot more columns/properties.

```r
# Libraries
library(dplyr)

# Seed
set.seed(12345)

# Property example
properties <- 
  tibble(property = c("a", "b", "c"),
         datatype = c("logical", "integer", "double"))

# Values example
values <- 
  tibble(a = sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE", "CORRECT"), 10, replace = TRUE),
         b = as.character(sample(c(1:9, 1.4), 10)),
         c = sample(c(-1.5:1.5, "word"), 10, replace = TRUE))

properties
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  property datatype
#  <chr>    <chr>   
#1 a        logical
#2 b        integer 
#3 c        double  

values
## A tibble: 10 x 3
#   a       b     c    
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr>
# 1 FALSE   7     -1.5 
# 2 CORRECT 1     word 
# 3 FALSE   8     1.5  
# 4 FALSE   1.4   -0.5 
# 5 TRUE    6     -0.5 
# 6 CORRECT 9     1.5  
# 7 FALSE   4     0.5  
# 8 FALSE   2     1.5  
# 9 CORRECT 3     -1.5 
#10 FALSE   5     -1.5
```

Part the my check will be to compare the amount of NAs per column before and after the transformation. This creates another problem as the double values will be automatically transformed to integers, while this is should become NA because it is a faulty data type (column b, row 4).

```r
# Prefered result
tibble(a = c(FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE), 
       b = c(7L, 1L, 8L, NA_integer_, 6L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), 
       c = c(-1.5, NA, 1.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5, -1.5))
## A tibble: 10 x 3
#   a         b     c
#   <lgl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 FALSE     7  -1.5
# 2 NA        1  NA  
# 3 FALSE     8   1.5
# 4 FALSE    NA  -0.5
# 5 TRUE      6  -0.5
# 6 NA        9   1.5
# 7 FALSE     4   0.5
# 8 FALSE     2   1.5
# 9 NA        3  -1.5
#10 FALSE     5  -1.5
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe relevant: we can set the column classes while importing. Import twice with classes and without, check NA counts?

Comment: Are the data types all "native R" data types? E.g. strings are called ```character```, etc. or do they need to be converted to be compared?

Comment: @Fnguyen Data types can be data "native R", so boolean == logical in my question.

Comment: @zx8754 not preferable and that does not solve the double to integer problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Add a `dplyr` solution

```r
properties <- mutate(properties,func_name =paste0("as.",datatype) )


values %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) match.fun(properties$func_name[match(deparse(substitute(x)),properties$property)])(x))
#> Warning in (function (x) : NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    a         b     c
#>    <lgl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1 FALSE     7  -1.5
#>  2 NA        1  NA  
#>  3 FALSE     8   1.5
#>  4 FALSE     1  -0.5
#>  5 TRUE      6  -0.5
#>  6 NA        9   1.5
#>  7 FALSE     4   0.5
#>  8 FALSE     2   1.5
#>  9 NA        3  -1.5
#> 10 FALSE     5  -1.5
```

Basically this can be done using `match.fun(funcname)`

```r
# Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Seed
set.seed(12345)

# Property example
properties <- 
  tibble(property = c("a", "b", "c"),
         datatype = c("logical", "integer", "double"))
       # datatype = c("boolean", "integer", "double"))
# Values example
values <- 
  tibble(a = sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE", "CORRECT"), 10, replace = TRUE),
         b = as.character(sample(c(1:9, 1.4), 10)),
         c = sample(c(-1.5:1.5, "word"), 10, replace = TRUE))


setDT(properties)
setDT(values)

properties[,func_name:=paste0("as.",datatype)]

for (i in names(values)){
  set(values,j = i,value=match.fun(properties[property==i,func_name])(values[[i]]))

  print(match.fun(properties[property==i,func_name]))
}
#> function (x, ...)  .Primitive("as.logical")
#> function (x, ...)  .Primitive("as.integer")
#> Warning in match.fun(properties[property == i, func_name])(values[[i]]): NAs
#> introduced by coercion
#> function (x, ...)  .Primitive("as.double")

values
#>         a b    c
#>  1: FALSE 7 -1.5
#>  2:    NA 1   NA
#>  3: FALSE 8  1.5
#>  4: FALSE 1 -0.5
#>  5:  TRUE 6 -0.5
#>  6:    NA 9  1.5
#>  7: FALSE 4  0.5
#>  8: FALSE 2  1.5
#>  9:    NA 3 -1.5
#> 10: FALSE 5 -1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I changed your "boolean" to "logical" as there is no function called `as.boolean`

You can also try `as.boolean <- as.logical` to avoid modify your exsiting codes.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Is this also possible using functions from the tidyverse? And any chance of filtering out doubles in the integer column "b" instead of automatically rounding them to integers?

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel update with a `dplyr` solution. For filter out doubles, you can try to  play with the strings like `grepl("\\d*\\.\\d+","1.5")`

Comment: I changed the `mutate_all` to `mutate_if` because it gives an error when there are other columns involved, e.g. id columns. Resulting in: `mutate_if(.predicate = names(.) %in% properties$property`.

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel yes you can play around this as long as it looping through columns

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code and see if it serves your purpose.

```
# Libraries
library(dplyr)

# Seed
set.seed(12345)

# Property example
properties <- 
  tibble(property = c("a", "b", "c"),
         datatype = c("logical", "integer", "double"))

# Values example
values <- 
  tibble( a = as.logical(sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE", "CORRECT"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
          b = sample(c(1:9, 1.4), 10) %>% ifelse( . -floor(.) == 0 , . ,NA ),
          c = as.numeric(sample(c(-1.5:1.5, "word"), 10, replace = TRUE)) )

Warning message:
In eval_tidy(xs[[i]], unique_output) : NAs introduced by coercion
values
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   a         b     c
   <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 FALSE     6  -1.5
 2 TRUE     NA  -0.5
 3 TRUE      3   1.5
 4 FALSE     5   0.5
 5 TRUE      2  -1.5
 6 NA        8   0.5
 7 TRUE      7   0.5
 8 TRUE      9   1.5
 9 NA        1  -1.5
10 NA        4  NA
```

You can check if it works for you, Cheers!

Comment: Obviously this works in my example, but the problem is that I have a dataset containing a multitude of these columns. For each column, the datatype needs to be changed in an automated way, not by manually changing all the columns data types.